# How to track ctr on slight page variations?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know there are solutions to split test landing pages but those tend to create two separate versions of the landing page. I want to track ctr (through a button on the page) and change the image on top on each visit to track which one is working better in terms of generating clicks on that button. Could that be achieved using some jquery+php script?

So, like on each page view one of the 2 images is displayed and each click through on the button is somehow tagged with the pic name.. so I can simply check which tag has got more number of clicks.

Comment: What is full form of ctr?

Comment: ctr is click through rate. Its the number of users that click on a specific link out of the total users that view a page